# How to add a AppleScript file to the Finder toolbar to execute the AppleScript?

Tags: finder, applescript

I have written an AppleScript to do a little task in the current folder of Finder. I added it to the Finder toolbar by dragging it while holding CMD-ALT. But when I click it, it opens the AppleScript in the Script Editor instead of executing it.

The AppleScript file has following rights: -rwxr-xr-x@

The owner is the same user which is using it.

Of course, it's my intention to execute the file, not to open it on button click. What do I need to do to execute it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want an **AppleScript** to *run* on its own, not in **Script Editor**, you need to change it from **File Format: Script** to **File Format: Application** in the **Save As** *sheet* when saving it.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! Is it the same for JavaScript .scpt files as well?

Comment: @andreas, yes it's the same for JavaScript in ScriptEditor, save it as an Application.